# How to remove the camera control buttons in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am currently trying to open camera in swift. I used thee following code to open the camera

```
   @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let cameraVC = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraVC.sourceType = .camera
    cameraVC.delegate = self
    self.present(cameraVC, animated: true)
}
```

What I want to do is remove the following buttons and extent camera to black areas

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a property `showsCameraControls`, set it to false then all default buttons will disappear. However, you have to implement all features by your hands. Try these codes:

```swift
private lazy var cameraVC: UIImagePickerController {
    let vc = UIImagePickerController()
    vc.showsCameraControls = false
    vc.sourceType = .camera
    vc.cameraOverlayView = captureButton
    //TODO: Set capture button frame wherever you want
    vc.delegate = self
    return vc
}()

private lazy var captureButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Take photo", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(capture), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.present(cameraVC, animated: true)
}

@objc private func takePhotoAction() {
    cameraVC.takePicture()
}
```

In case you want to customize more, I recommend using `AVCaptureSession` instead. It's easier to manipulate.

Output

[image]

Comment: yes but how to to remove that black area

Comment: @Ahmed using `cameraViewTransform`. For example, this is to make camera equal 3/4 screen. var ratio = 4.0 / 3.0; var scale = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * ratio)); cameraVC.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)